# No Matching Results error covers my toolbar

Tags: cpanel

I am getting an error that covers the menu of my Joomla admin page and cannot get rid of it. It says "No Matching Results".

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You might need to provide a little more detail to keep this question open.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a module causing this issue. Try disabling your modules (last ones installed first) one by one (deleting your Joomla/browser cache every time disable a module) until the problem is resolved (this way you will be able to find the culprit module easily).

Comment: Thanks. My issue is that the message "No Matching Results" is covering the "Save" & "Save and Close". So I can make a change to a module, but cannot save the change because of the error message.

Comment: This seems like an administrator module. Go to the module manager, and then switch "Site" on the left to the "Administrator" and then check the modules, and disable them by one by one (starting with the one with the highest ID) - you don't need to open a module, just check the green checkmark next to it to convert it into a red x. Alternatively, this might be a plugin, so, again, do the same with plugins.

Comment: You are awesome! The highest ID, which was the last module I created was the culprit. Thanks a bunch!!